# How to Add Pagination to Page?

Tags: pagination

I follow the instructions in https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-split-wordpress-posts-into-multiple-pages/ to add <!––nextpage––> tag to my page in classic editor, see below:

[image]

However, the page is still not paginated, see https://exchange-repair.com/test-pagination/

I also try that on a post, but still not working, see https://exchange-repair.com/9-2/

To eliminate any side-effects, I use the default them "Twenty Twenty-One", see below:

[image]

I check the HTML source of the page and see the following:

```
    <div class="entry-content">
        <p>abc<br />
<!––nextpage––><br />
def</p>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

Why?

Comment: How are you outputting the content in your page template?

Comment: @JacobPeattie, I check the page and find it use "Default Template". I check Theme Editor but cannot find a template called Default Template.

Comment: If you didn’t develop the theme yourself then this is an issue you’ll need to raise with the theme author.

Comment: @alancc are you 100% sure that you used the HTML/Text (**non-Visual**) mode of the (classic) editor to enter the `<!––nextpage––>` tag? Also, if you're using the block editor, then you could easily add page breaks using the [Page Break Block](https://wordpress.org/support/article/page-break-block/).

Comment: @JacobPeattie, thank you for your advice, I try on the default WP theme "Twenty Twenty-One", but still get the same result.

Comment: I think the issue is the type of dash you have. Try `<!--nextpage-->` instead of `<!––nextpage––>`

Comment: @cameronjonesweb, Thank you very much. That works. I should not use copy & paste method to input the <!--nextpage-->